# A very simple Dynamic Button label is not updating when state changes

Tags: dynamic, color, gui-construction, button, user-interface

Just when I thought I had `Dynamic` tackled for most non-complex controls, this comes along and makes a mockery of me. So what the `Button` label should do when pressed if `state -> True` is turn `Green` otherwise `Black`.

I know it's embarrassing to ask, but please help if you know what' wrong.

```
autosave[] := Module[{
   state := CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave],
   toggle := 
    If[state, 
     CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave] = False, 
     CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave] = True],
   label = 
    If[state, Style["AutoSave", Darker@Green], 
     Style["AutoSave", Darker@Green]]
   },
  Button[Dynamic[label], Dynamic[toggle]]
  ]

autosave[]
```

Comment: You are using `Darker[Green]` for both cases. Is that a copy-paste error or your actual code?

Comment: Also, the `Dynamic` around `toggle`shouldn't be there: It should be `Button[Dynamic[label], toggle]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what is wrong, we store the code for the button like:

```
autosave[] := 
 bt = Module[{state := 
     CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave], 
    toggle := 
     If[state, 
      CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave] = False, 
      CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave] = True], 
    label = If[state, Style["AutoSave", Darker@Green], 
      Style["AutoSave", Darker@Green]]}, 
   Button[Dynamic[label], Dynamic[toggle]]]
```

Then we can look at the button code:

```
??bt
```

[image]

You see that the symbol for the label has been renamed by module to label$25080 (the number will change). And the value is:

[image]

Now it is clear that the style color is fixed to RGBColor[0, 2/3, 0]. If you look at the definition of label you notice that you should set it to "SetDelayed" otherwise it will evaluate once for all.

Further, to see different colors of the button you must use 2 different colors. Here is your fixed code:

```
autosave[] := 
 Module[{state := 
    CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave], 
   toggle := 
    If[state, 
     CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave] = False, 
     CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave] = True], 
   label := 
    If[state, Style["AutoSave", Darker@Green], 
     Style["AutoSave", Red]]}, 
  Button[Dynamic[label], Dynamic[toggle]]]
```

Comment: thank you for catching my careless errors. i was aware that i needed two colors.  i used the first `Style` as a copy/paste for second `Style` and forgot to change it. i did intend a set delayed `label := . . ,`. and im certain i typed it but im using a poor quality keyboard at the moment. btw your solution didnt work for me but thats okay i fixed it.